# Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Contact'

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

**Error**
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Contact'.
Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact': id, contactType, name *ts(2345)*

```
const contact: {
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

I have a problem with this error. I'm trying to download a contact in my expo app.

My Code `download.tsx`:

```
const downloadContact = async (customer: any) => {
    if(hasContactPermission) {
        const contact = {
            [Contacts.Fields.Name]: customer.name,
            [Contacts.Fields.Emails]: customer.email,
            [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers]: customer.phone,
        };
        const contactId = await Contacts.addContactAsync(contact);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having an issue with the type inference, the contact object you are sending lacks on required parameters like `id, contactType, name, etc`. For properties that you don't currently have you have to use the `?` operator to mark that they can be `undefined`

```
interface IContact: {
    id?: string;
    contactType?: string // <- using the ? marks them as optional parameters
    name: string // <- if the name is not provided the ts complier will complain
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

And the method to add contacts should be something like

```
class Contacts {
    ...
    addContactAsync: (contact: IContact) => { ... }
}
```